# Flex : Assignment in Conditionals

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, language-features

```
If I use an Assignment within conditional, for e.g.
if(userType='admin')
Flex throws a warning,unlike Java, which throws an error.
Why should Flex be doing this, despite being one of the newest languages?

1100: Assignment within conditional.  Did you mean == instead of =?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because assignments have a value in Actionscript, which makes that syntax legal, and they don't have a value in Java, which makes it not. The difference comes because despite recent Java-izations, Actionscript is descended from ECMAScript. Other consequences of this design are the ability to make statements like this:

```
var foo:Number = 0;
var bar:Number = 0;
foo = bar = 2;
assertEquals(2, foo);
assertEquals(2, bar);
```

IMO, this is the best behavior it could have - it doesn't break compatibility with older versions of Actionscript, and it doesn't remove language functionality for the purpose of handholding, but it does bring a common error to the attention of the user.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the compiler probably automatically fixes it?

It is interesting though that Flex would do that.

(and btw, it's not "Flex", it's Actionscript 3)